# Image inside canvas crop with custom rectangle JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-plugins, html5-canvas

I have a Canvas element with inside an image ( the canvas has the same dimension of the image), i want to crop this image using a selection rectangle! For my project i use the javascript's framework JQuery and i'm searching a plugin that implementing a custom selection rectangle on canvas!
Anyone know one plugin that do this (I founded a lot of plugin that implements this functionality but only on  elements)?
If no, what is the way to implement a custom rectangle on Canvas elements?

I hope in yours answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did you tried using [`Fabric.js`](http://kangax.github.com/fabric.js/kitchensink/) to generate rectangle on Canvas ?

Answer (score 1):

Usually, everything that is drawn onto a canvas will automatically change the canvas content. If you want to draw a rectangle with the mouse without destroying the underlying canvas, the usual way is to add an additional (temporary) canvas on top of the original canvas. The new canvas has a transparent background, so the underlying canvas is fully visible.

Now you draw the rectangle on the temporary canvas (which has the same dimensions as the origianl) and store the coordinates of the selection to apply the crop process on the original.

Please see my example here: http://jsbin.com/apitak/4